# Do I have to pay my debt collector if I collect my debt myself?

Tags: contract-law

I setup an account with a debt collection service. The collectors will collect my debt for a percent taken from the owed amount. If I sue my client for unpaid debt and win a summons proceeding, do I have to pay my collector? Nothing to this effect was written in the collector's contract between us.

Comment: *Nothing to this effect was written in the collector's contract between us*.  This can be read two ways. My critical reading tells me that it's not in the contract because it's not an option. And of course collecting a debt and winning a judgment are two different things.

Comment: Is it a third-party agency acting on your behalf, or did you sell the debt to a debt buyer?

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the contract itself. Double check your contract. Most of the times, these contracts are ***exclusive***. Meaning, you do have to pay them. That, or they outright buy the debt from you and you don't own it anymore. That said, I will take your statement "*Nothing to this effect was written in the collector's contract between us.*" to mean the question of you collecting your own debt is not referenced at all by the contract. In that case...

> **If it's not in the contact, I don't think you have to pay them.**

The principle of ***ei incumbit probatio qui dicit*** (*proof lies on him who asserts*) seems to apply here.

*Disclaimer: I'm not an attorney. Consult a real attorney before you do anything based on this answer.*